# Datafactory Azure SSIS Integration Runtime notes in Queue though job succeeded

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

I have the issue where within datafactory Azure SSIS integration runtime, the pipeline is triggered to run an SSIS package, the package completes but within datafactory stays open noting "... in progress", whereby all subsequent pipeline runs sit in queue:

[image]

The only way I have been able to alleviate this is to restart the integration runtime almost daily.
How can I alleviate this?

Comment: How often did you trigger the pipeline running? As I know about Data Factory, Data Factory need 5 minutes to prepare the next pipeline running.

Comment: @LeonYue I am triggering every 5 min. The problem is that nothing officially fails, it just waits in queue forever and never runs and that we only occasionally see this issue, like once a month...

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?